# ExpressJs: Can't access object property from handlebars template

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

My Routes:

```js
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
  next();
});

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(res.locals.currentUser.username); ==>> this is getting printed in console.
    res.render('index');
});
```

My index.handelbars

```
{{currentUser}} ===> this is getting displayed
{{currentUser.username}} ===> this is not
```

My User Schema

```
const UserSchema =
    new Schema({
        fullName: String,
        username: { type: String, required: true },
        password: { type: String, required: true },
        isMember: { type: Boolean, default: false },
        isAdmin: { type: Boolean, default: false }
    });
```

I am trying to access one of 'currentUser' object's property. Although the object itself gets displayed in the template but its property doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Change this

res.locals.currentUser = req.user;

to

```
res.locals.currentUser = req.user.lean(); // add lean()
```

Comment: could also use toObject() method.
Apparently, the latest version of HandleBars wouldn't let you use prototype methods or properties of an object.